# kivymd MDProgressBar UI not updating even with threading

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have the below code in test.py and test.kv.
The MDProgressBar UI does not move until end of the program. I've read similar questions in stackoverflow but the solutions posted were only snippets.

Assuming *self.process_some_data*() is a function that takes a long while to complete, the MDProgressBar UI instance *self.progress_bar* is supposed to reflect current progress. Based on solutions from other forum posts, I've

- created a thread for *self.process_some_data*() function.
- used *Clock.schedule_once*() for *self.update_progress_bar*() function which updates *self.progress_bar.value* in main thread at different stages of completion.
- included decorator @mainthread for *self.update_progress_bar*() function which does not seem to make any difference.

Feel free to edit the code and repost the full solution. Thanks.

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivymd.uix.progressbar import MDProgressBar 
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import time
import threading
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from functools import partial

 
class Screen1(Screen):        
    def show_popup(self):
        self.progress_bar = MDProgressBar()
        self.popup = Popup(
            title ='Progress',
            content = self.progress_bar,
            auto_dismiss = False,   # dialog does NOT close if click outside it
            size_hint = (None, None),
            size = (400, 400)
        )
        self.popup.bind( on_open = lambda x: self.run_thread() )
        # self.progress_bar.max = 100
        self.progress_bar.value = 10
        
        self.popup.open()
        print(self.progress_bar.value)

        
    @mainthread
    def update_progress_bar(self, val, _):
        self.progress_bar.value = val
        print(self.progress_bar.value)
        
        if val >= 100:
            # self.popup.dismiss()  
            dialog = MDDialog(title="Status", text="Completed")
            dialog.open()            


    def run_thread(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.process_some_data())
        t1.start()
        # t1.join()
        
    def process_some_data(self):          
        time.sleep(1)   # simulate program is running something
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update_progress_bar, 25), 0)

        time.sleep(1)   # simulate program is running something
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update_progress_bar, 50), 0)

        time.sleep(1)   # simulate program is running something
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update_progress_bar, 75), 0)

        time.sleep(1)   # simulate program is running something
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update_progress_bar, 100), 0)

    
# Create the App class 
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("test.kv")
 

# run the App
if __name__ in ("__main__"):
    MyApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
Screen1:
        
    Button:
        text: "Run program"
        on_release: root.show_popup()
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `run_thread()` method, the line:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.process_some_data())
```

runs the `process_some_data()` method, then sets the target of the created thread to the return of that method. I think you just need to remove the `()` from that method, so that the target is set to the `process_some_data` method and not its return:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.process_some_data)
```